# How to set isBase64Encoded: True in laravel response

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-response

I'm building an application on `Laravel 8` and hosting the app on `AWS lambda`. I want to compress the response with `gzip` to HTTP request. I had interaction with AWS support and they asked me to add headers with `'Content-Encoding' => 'gzip',` and also add `isBase64Encoded` to `true`. To achieve this I tried finding out the solution over the internet I found out a documentation for Laravel Vapor which handles this perfectly. They made an middleware which adds these attributes:

```
$response = $next($request);

if (in_array('gzip', $request->getEncodings()) && function_exists('gzencode')) {
    $response->setContent(gzencode($response->getContent(), 9));
    $response->headers->add([
        'Content-Encoding' => 'gzip',
        'X-Vapor-Base64-Encode' => 'True',
    ]);
}
return $response;
```

My current header looks like:

[image]

Since I'm not using Laravel Vapor So I need to put `isBase64Encoded` into the header:

I tried executing this via:

```
$response = $next($request);

if (in_array('gzip', $request->getEncodings()) && function_exists('gzencode')) {
    $response->setContent(gzencode($response->getContent(), 9));
    $response->headers->add([
        'Content-Encoding' => 'gzip',
    ]);
    
    $response->isBase64Encoded = true;
    
    dd($response);
}
return $response;
```

As you can see I'm trying to add attribute by `$response->isBase64Encoded = true;`, once implemented the header changes to something unexpected:

[image]

Also the content is not encoded. Help me out in adding the `isBase64Encoded` attributes in response

Comment: what if you don't use gzip for now , and only check if base64 is working!?